# Can I double spend this transaction?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, doublespend

b9d6d458f312b6ce2ef27bbb4a4a88f95e4a5db7aa04c9ab1f6225ecde47a77e

Can I move it ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, most likely, if you sent using a software wallet. Not a chance, if sent from an exchange where you don't have control of the private key.

Answer (score 1):

"Can I double spend this transaction?" as long as the transaction is unconfirmed you can try to make a new transaction with the same transaction-details but a noticeable higher fee. then you must hope that your new transaction (with the higher fee) will be executed before your b9d6d...-transaction will be executed. if this works the result would be that the b9d6d...-transaction will never be executed in future because there are not enough funds on your 1GDvWJUd7Hy...-adress. did you mean this by writing "double spend"?

Comment: anion hi                 Yes that is what I meant. I guess my public key changes after each transaction. Can I steel make double spending ?